# transitionDuration function does not exist in nvd3.js

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm learning *nvd3.js* to draw charts. From a sample from the site, I pick following simple code to test:

```
chart = nv.models.lineChart()
                      .margin({ left: 100, right: 100 })  //Adjust chart margins to give the x-axis some breathing room.
                      .useInteractiveGuideline(true)  //We want nice looking tooltips and a guideline!
                      .transitionDuration(350)  //how fast do you want the lines to transition?
                      .showLegend(true)       //Show the legend, allowing users to turn on/off line series.
                      .showYAxis(true)        //Show the y-axis
                      .showXAxis(true)        //Show the x-axis
```

But when I'm running the code it says that `transitionDuration` doesn't exist. If I remove that line everything works fine.

**Question:** Why this function doesn't exist? Am I wrong somewhere or is there any additional library required to be loaded?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The function `.transitionDuration()` had a rather short-lived guest appearance within NVD3's lineChart. It is gone by the time of writing, but continues to cause confusion, mostly because the page's [*Simple Line Chart*](http://nvd3.org/examples/line.html) example still refers to it. However, the lineChart example on the NVD3.js page is broken and should no longer be used. For an up-to-date list of examples the site recommends cloning the [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/novus/nvd3).

The function `.transitionDuration()` was introduced by commit [`d57a84`](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/commit/d57fa841cab707f09f7b401ed4e467c6b826ab4e#diff-a175d009dcb5dacbee0ae7d227baf457) in August 2013 and was deprecated by commit [`e177cae`](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/commit/e177cae4d23f7423f2b38e9d2a53cda376b23382#diff-a175d009dcb5dacbee0ae7d227baf457) just five months later. As can be seen from its GitHub history, it has been [forwarding to `chart.duration()`](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/e177cae4d23f7423f2b38e9d2a53cda376b23382/src/models/lineChart.js#L465-L468) some time afterwards:

```
chart.transitionDuration = function(_) {        
    nv.deprecated('lineChart.transitionDuration');      
    return chart.duration(_);       
};
```

The function was finally removed by commit [`92ec4bc`](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/commit/92ec4bc041fd60492eecd1d670b1895ffa1d423c#diff-a175d009dcb5dacbee0ae7d227baf457) and is therefore no longer available. As a direct replacement you may call function `.duration()` of [lineChart](http://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#lineChart).

Alternatively, the chart may be configured by calling `chart.options()` passing in the `duration` as a property of the options object.

```
chart = nv.models.lineChart()
    .options({
        duration: 500
    })
;
```

**Update Nov 9, 2015**

<strike>Ironically, even the new example from the GitHub repository is flawed. It uses the wrong property name `transitionDuration` in the options object used for configuration. This will just add the property `transitionDuration` which will do no harm and throw no errors because it is unknown, but will have no effect either. It needs to be changed to `duration` to achieve the desired effect.</strike>

```
chart = nv.models.lineChart()
    .options({
        transitionDuration: 300,    // This should be duration: 300
        useInteractiveGuideline: true
    })
;
```

**Update Aug 19, 2016**

The above mentioned shortcoming in the lineChart example from the GitHub repository was fixed as of May 21, 2016 by commit [a683c97](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/commit/a683c97725822cffb00f292ae2fafbbf9958173a#diff-23f4e7abf6ec2e4c86e2a2e94d6acce2).

Answer (score 4):

Adding this answer for anyone else who happens to stumble upon this issue with bad sample code -- the examples on NVD3.org are outdated, and the site currently suggests to clone the Github repository for the latest examples. For a line chart, the latest example is here: https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/examples/lineChart.html

Comment: As stated in @altocumulus 's answer, the `transitionDuration` option is deprecated.  Use `duration` instead.  e.g. `duration: 300` not `transitionDuration: 300`.